# Sync/choice-evt over multiple channels (number determined at runtime)

Tags: racket

I am trying to create a very simple program, intended to measure the time required to select and synchronise across multiple channels.  Essentially, the concept is simply that I have one sender and one receiver.  Throughout multiple iterations, the sender randomly selects one of the channels the two have been provided and sends a message on that channel.  As part of this, I need to be able to control the number of channels involved as a command-line parameter to the program, so I can't hard-code a pre-determined number of channels into the program.  The problem is, I can't figure out how to get either `sync` or `choice-evt` from the [Synchronisation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/all-sync.html) module to work with multiple channels.

The entire program (as I currently have it) is below:

```
#lang racket

(provide main)
(require racket/random)

(define (sender iterations channels)
  (match iterations
    [0 (displayln "sender completed")]
    [iter 
           (let ([choice-chan (random-ref channels)])
             (channel-put choice-chan iter)
             (sender (- iter 1) channels))]))

(define (receiver iterations channels notification-semaphore)
  (match iterations
    [0 (begin
         (displayln "receiver completed")
         (semaphore-post notification-semaphore))]
    [iter
     (let ([ignored-choice (sync (choice-evt (vector->values channels)))])
        (begin (displayln ignored-choice)
        (receiver (- iter 1) channels notification-semaphore)))]))

(define (experiment iterations num-channels)
  (let ([channels
         (vector->immutable-vector
          (build-vector num-channels (λ (i) (make-channel))))]
        [notification-semaphore (make-semaphore)])
    (thread (λ () (receiver iterations channels notification-semaphore)))
    (thread (λ () (sender iterations channels)))
    (semaphore-wait notification-semaphore)))

(define (main iterations num-channels)
  (experiment (string->number iterations) (string->number num-channels))
  (displayln "SelectTime completed successfully"))
```

The `displayln` expressions aren't strictly necessary, they're just there so that I can see that there is indeed something being passed from sender to receiver.

The issue I have is that, when I use only a single channel, everything seems to work fine.  With two or more channels, however, I get a runtime error complaining about an arity mismatch - 1 value was expected but 2 (or more if I specified more on the command line) were provided.  Best as I can tell, this error occurs inside the `receiver` function at the evaluation of `(choice-evt (vector->values channels))`, after processing the inner expression.  I have tried every variation I can think of, such as using `channels` directly without the `vector->values`; changing the vector to a list; dropping the `choice-evt` (especially since, if I'm reading the docs right, that isn't actually necessary for my test); moving where the `sync` happens out of the variable declaration in the `let`.

How can I sync over multiple channels, when the number of channels won't be known at runtime?  It looks like using a vector or list isn't the correct way to go about this, but I'm a bit stumped as to what *is* the correct way.

P.S.  Please do feel free to critique the program in other ways while you're answering if you think that might be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` to make a `choice-evt` from a variable-length *list* of channels. For example, in your code above, change the `sync` call to the following:

```
(sync (apply choice-evt (vector->list channels)))
```